# Hide div if URL contains word

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hide, contains

I need to hide a div if the url of the page contains a certain word. Thanks to this site I have been able to successfully find if the url contains the word. This code works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href.indexOf("Bar-Ends") != -1) {
alert("your url contains bar ends");
}
</script>
```

but for some reason it will not work to hide a div, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href.indexOf("Bar-Ends") != -1) {
$("#notBarEnds").hide();
}
</script>

<div id="notBarEnds">this is not bar ends</div>
```

Anyone have any idea what is wrong with this code?
Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Defer the execution of that snippet, because the element does not exist (yet) when the script is evaluated.

Comment: Based on what you've provided, you're not invoking this code on DOM ready, therefore the element `$('#notBarEnds')` is not prepared and you cannot invoke events against it. wrap this in `$(function(){ //code })`

Comment: I think you can also put a $(document).ready() around the js and it will work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notice the reorder:

```
<div id="notBarEnds">this is not bar ends</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href.indexOf("Bar-Ends") != -1) {
$("#notBarEnds").hide();
}
</script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("Bar-Ends") != -1) {
        $("#notBarEnds").hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

Waiting for the entire document to be "ready"

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("Bar-Ends") != -1) {
    $("#notBarEnds").hide();
  }
});
```

Your div hasn't necessarily loaded yet when the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

You're running an inline script as the HTML is being constructed, there isn't a `div` named `#notBarEnds` at the time that the script runs, you need to run it as a function after the document has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

i write it without checking it, if doesn't work change de regex :D

```
$(document).on('ready', function()
{
    if(window.location.href.match(/Bar\-Ends/i))
        $("#notBarEnds").hide();
});
```