# Hide div in iframe if URL contains word

Tags: javascript, iframe

How can I hide a div within an iframe if the main URL contains a specific word?

@  [Hide div if URL contains word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436586/hide-div-if-url-contains-word) describes how to do this but does not work within an iframe. Is there a way to do this?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href.indexOf("login") != -1) {
$("#slidewrap").hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: suggestion: put a sample up on jsfiddle.net that shows the behavior you're seeing

Comment: @jcollum Seems like it might be tricky to replicate iframe issues on jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder... Yep: "Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.w3schools.com"."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well you would need to reference the content IN the iframe. They are different documents.

```
$("iframe").contents().find("#slidewrap").hide();
```

It would be better if you used the id of the frame

Comment: Decided to take your advice and use the id of the frame. Thank you!